# Find out the column number in which Maxima occur in a matrix in Mata in a for-loop

Tags: loops, matrix, max, stata

My purpose is not to find out what the maximum value is but the column number(S) in which the maximum occurs when generated different random numbers ~N to the entire column elements of the row.

A potential problem here is what if two or more elements in the same row contain the same value which is the maximum? I know it is unlikely for they content are real numbers. But I preset all elements in first row to be zero. Therefore, in the first round, all values are maximum and are subject to next conditional action.

I will want the column number(s) to do further computation in the next round of loop

Suppose all the matrix are well defined before the for-loop to save space here.

```
Mata:
for (k=1; k<=10; k++){ 
for (j=1; j<=20; i++){ 
A[k,j]= sum[k,j] \ count [1,j]
}
   Choose max A[k,j]
   For that j*   for max A[k,j*] to occur
        {count[1,j*]=count[1, j*+1]
            y= rnormal(1,1,x,5)
            C[k,j*]=y
            sum[k,j*]=sum[k,j*]+c[k,j*]
            }

}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow most of this -- a lot seems to be background tangential to your question -- but if the question is to find the column index of the largest element in a row vector, here is one technique:

```
: y = rnormal(1,10,0,1)

: y
                  1              2              3              4              5
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |   .3660763572    .4824003439   -.4441589685    .4314199623   -1.422563986
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  6              7              8              9             10
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1    -1.226056129     1.18790502   -.4106889581    1.024620896    1.092570732  |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

: select((1..10), (y :== max(y)))
7
```

(LATER)

I haven't tried to grasp the whole of what you are trying to do, but you are making very bold assertions about a language you have only just started to learn.

Generally, `select()` will take a matrix as first argument.

Specifically, there is no problem in identifying the maximum in a matrix.

```
: y = rnormal(5,5,0,1)

: max(y)
2.001071729

: y :== max(y)
        1   2   3   4   5
       +---------------------+
     1 |  0   0   0   0   0  |
     2 |  0   0   0   0   1  |
     3 |  0   0   0   0   0  |
     4 |  0   0   0   0   0  |
     5 |  0   0   0   0   0  |
       +---------------------+
```

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I looked more into -select- and did some trial. Select() works with vector only. Suppose y is a matrix, there is no such thing as y :== max(y[2,.])

Comment: You are tremendously helpful. And I apologize for my ignorance and arrogance. STATA(MATA) is such a useful tool. Thank you and Martin for the help. I got inspiration and focus of direction from you two. The statalist archive is useful too. 
I was wrong about select() earlier,it can come from a matrix but it deals with vector at a time. I had success with vertical vector but not horizontal vector. Will continue to explore about this if have chance. Please read my final code in answer. 
Again, thank you and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (k=2; k<=n; k++){ 
   for (j=1; j<=50; j++){ 
      Ri[k,j]= sumAi[1,j] / count[1,j]
   }      
   Maxj= select((1..50), (Ri[k,]:==max(Ri[k,])))
   count[1,Maxj]=count[1,Maxj]+1
   y= rnormal(1,1,x,5)
   Ai[k,Maxj]=y
   sumAi[1,Maxj]=sumAi[1,Maxj]+y
   Maxj=.
   }
```